# SonarQube Won't Start After Resart (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-18.04

I have recently installed SonarQube on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. After the install I was able to successfully start the service and visit the web portal. After a restart, the service would no longer start.

## Environment

- SonarQube: 6.7.4/7.1 (I've tried both)
- Java:

  openjdk 9-Ubuntu

  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4)

  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4, mixed mode)
- PostgreSQL: psql (PostgreSQL) 10.4 (Ubuntu 10.4-0ubuntu0.18.04)
- Ubuntu: 18.04

## Log File Message

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.06.12 20:41:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2018.06.12 20:41:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.06.12 20:41:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es
2018.06.12 20:41:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2018.06.12 20:41:06 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.06.12 20:41:06 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/opt/sonarqube/lib/common/netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007ff47b6639df, pid=5467, tid=5514
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-Ubuntu+0-9b181-4, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, concurrent mark sweep gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 3314 c2 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.ByteQuadsCanonicalizer.calcHash([II)I (115 bytes) @ 0x00007ff47b6639df [0x00007ff47b6638a0+0x000000000000013f]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/core.5467)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid5467.log
Compiled method (c2)    8169 3314       4       com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.ByteQuadsCanonicalizer::calcHash (115 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007ff47b663710,0x00007ff47b663c20] = 1296
 relocation     [0x00007ff47b663880,0x00007ff47b6638a0] = 32
 main code      [0x00007ff47b6638a0,0x00007ff47b663b20] = 640
 stub code      [0x00007ff47b663b20,0x00007ff47b663b38] = 24
 oops           [0x00007ff47b663b38,0x00007ff47b663b40] = 8
 metadata       [0x00007ff47b663b40,0x00007ff47b663b48] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007ff47b663b48,0x00007ff47b663ba8] = 96
 scopes pcs     [0x00007ff47b663ba8,0x00007ff47b663c08] = 96
 dependencies   [0x00007ff47b663c08,0x00007ff47b663c10] = 8
 nul chk table  [0x00007ff47b663c10,0x00007ff47b663c20] = 16
Could not load hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
2018.06.12 20:41:15 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 134
2018.06.12 20:41:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.06.12 20:41:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Update: Corrected the Ubuntu version number in title.

Comment: Try to start SonarQube without any plugins. Also try to run a small Java test program on that machine. The SDK is not required; only JRE 8 is needed.

Comment: @JeroenHeier 
As far as I know SonarQube doesn't have any plugins installed (the plugins directory is empty)

I have several other Java applications running on the box including ActiveMQ and Jenkins (all running fine), but I have both Java 8 and 9 installed (don't know if that's relevant) The output of `update-java-alternatives -l` is :  
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64       1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64

Please let me know if there are other details I can provide. Thank you!

Comment: I switch back to a JRE **8** and it works fine. It seems to be due to a Netty + Java 9 issue. See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/7254

Comment: I don't think it is the Netty issue. If I overwrite the data folder in the installation directory, everything runs fine until the next reboot.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I am overwriting the data directory from a freshly unzipped installation.

Comment: Also works if instead of overwriting the _data_ folder, just deleting the _es5_ folder underneath the _data_ folder

Comment: Deleting the "indices" folder under the _(installationDirectory)/data/es5/nodes/0_ directory seems to do the trick. Still working on a more specific cause.

Comment: @DillonAdams Saved the day.